# Automatically generate raw thumbnails only with gThumb

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 18.04, thumbnails, gthumb

I would like to generate camera raw file thumbnails (Nikon .NEF) in Nautilus with gThumb, without opening the app, and when no additional thumbnailer is installed. Some script or a Terminal command, I guess.

When a folder with pictures is opened in gThumb's folders browser it generates thumbnails in `/home/.thumbnails` if the thumbnail for that file is not already there. Also, can it be done just by opening the folder with the raw files in Nautilus, as a thumbnailer would do it?

For the moment gnome-raw-thumbnailer and ufraw-batch are buggy for 18.04, gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer generates low-quality thumbnails for raw files, so I'm not using any of them. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the thumbnails to be created automatically, exactly as gThumb would do it, but without having to go through the directories in gThumb, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Shouldn’t nautilus already create thumbnails by default? Did you try setting the `gconf` key “/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_image_thumbnails” to “always” (see [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327578))?

Comment: It's set like that. Nautilus is generating thumbnails through thumbnailers which I disabled for .nef files because I didn't like the result. So that's why I want to generate them through gThumb.

Comment: Ah, sorry for being slow on the uptake – which image properties (geometry, extension) do you have in mind? Do you know how nautilus manages to link image and thumbnail? Path and filename format would be good to know, e.g. `~/.thumbnails/normal/image.JPG_thumb.png` for a file `image.JPG` – unfortunately I can’t test this myself.

Comment: Rats, unfortunately [ImageMagick can’t write NEF files](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)… :/